# Microsoft Orleans 2.0 grain Delay

Tags: c#

I'm using Microsoft Orleans 2.0 for Concurrency management and having a issue in long running task exception is:

> Response is not coming 30 sec

So I want this grain to be active around 2 min.
Is there any solution?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/orleans/issues/1698

Comment: I dont know your business case but MS Orleans methods should be fast. Maybe you could set grain as reentrant and then have one method that will start the job and another method that will check if job is done and return the result. Please share your scenario and maybe we could help you more.
For long running tasks, lets call them jobs, i would use some messaging broker eg. RabbitMq. Best,
Dean